Quantum description of the Classical Hall Effect
Using the linear regime of the Hall effect is a quick and effective way of measuring the carrier density of a two dimensional electron gas. Let's call this denisty $n_{linear}$. This density is typically in very good agreement with the density that underlies the SDH oscillations in longitudinal resistivity and the positions of Quantum Hall plateaus, let's call this $n_{SDH}$. Given these oscillations are due to well understood edge states, this density can be considered very accurate. In a well behaved two dimensional electron gas, $n_{linear}$ and $n_{SDH}$ are typically very close in value. That is, $n_{linear}$ essentially gives the correct carrier density.
My question is essentially, why is $n_{classical}$ such a good measure of carrier density? Why does the slope of the linear Hall give the correct carrier density when it does not rely on a quantum mechanical description of the two dimensional electron gas, but rather the Drude model?
The magnitude of the magnetic fields I am concerned about are too small for clear, quantised edge state formation. Thus the quantum Hall effect is not relevant. I am concerned about the case where the effect of the magnetic field is a small pertubation.
In a typical Drude model text book derivation all carriers drift with the same velocity and the current in a Hall bar is expressed as
$I=nevW$,
where $v$ is drift velocity and $W$ is sample width. Equating the Lorentz force and the force due to the Hall field leads to,
$Bev=eE_{y}=eV_y/W$,
where $B$ is the perpendicular field, $E_y$ is the Hall field and $V_y$ is the Hall voltage. This leads to a drift velocity of,
$v=V_y/WB$.
Subbing the drift velocity here into the current equation results in,
$I=neV_y/B$.
This leads to a Hall resistance of
$R_{xy}=V_y/I = B/ne$.
Hence if $m$ is the slope of a plot of $R_{xy}$ agsint B, $n_{linear}$=1/me.
Now, the key assumptions here have been that all carriers are drifting at the same drift velocity, $v$, and that all carriers contribute to conduction. However this is not the case. The situation is not classical. In fact, the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are momentum eigenstates with a quadratic dispersion relation. Furthermore, only the electrons at the Fermi level are responsible for conduction and their velocities are all very different. One can imagine raising and lowering the chemical potential at opposite ends of the Hall bar to achieve a net current. The states between these two local chemical potentials, around the Fermi level, are responsible for conduction.  At the Fermi level we have electrons travelling in all directions.
How can one use the actual, quadratic dispersion relation of the electrons in a two dimensional electron gas and the fact that conduction is due to a small number of states around the Fermi level and still derive the same Hall effect?

If you find that the Drude model is too simplistic and unrealistic, you could always redo the derivation under the NFE model. Most of your questions here would be best answered by such a derivation. It just turns out that the classical density and the quantum version thereof are almost the same, and the silver lining due to the displacement of the Fermi surface, all of which have rather high velocities, average out to the appropriate classical drift velocity, and so Drude model can be somewhat accidentally correct.
